Angular 17: NG0100 on new control flows
A few weeks ago we migrated our Angular application to Angular 17. While doing that we also used the Angular CLI command to change all control-flows to the new built-in control-flows. This worked fine and at the first look, all works like before.
However, a few days ago I fell over a "NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked" where no error was before the change. And I'm struggeling in finding a solution for that.
What we have is a component with a BehaviorSubject. This BehaviorSubject is used in the child components to provide informations on its loading state to the parent component. In the HTML, this looks like that:
@if (childComponentLoadingState$ | async; as childComponentLoadingState) {
  ...
  
  <mat-stepper linear #myStepper>
    <mat-step [completed]="isFirstStepCompleted(childComponentLoadingState)">
      ...
      <my-child-component [componentLoadingState$]="childComponentLoadingState$">
      </my-child-component>
      ...
    </mat-step> 
    ...
  </mat-stepper>

  ...
}

As long as we used *ngIf this worked fine and we didn't get any error. Now in the implementation provided, we get an "NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked" in the line of the mat-step tag.
Has anyone any idea why there is an error now and how we can solve it? Thanks for your help! :)

Without a working repro, this is hardy actionnable.

The question description is good. But, maybe it needs more detail about context, like code of related files.

First of all the new angular control flows are in developer preview and therefore not stable Control Flows. Now if you wish to work with the experimental control flows NG0100 has to do with change detection, without the knowledge of your code I would suggest the following:

manually detectChanges after content was checked
use RXJS operators on your subject to detectChanges for example pipe
and tap
revert to the *ngIf directive since it solves your issue and is stable

import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}   
    
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}


it''s not stable meaning it can have some breeaking changes in the future. It's still fully polished feature, and it's not experimental
